# Fragment Transition

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, transition, shared

I currently have this setup which is done using a navigation drawer and a view pager which handles all the fragments and its transitions.

[image: Fragments]

What i want to achieve is to completely replace the above screen to this screen.
So when a user clicks on the image it would go to the next screen as shown below.The next screen does not contain any tabs or a navigation drawer its just meant to show more details about the item clicked.Should i use a fragment or an activity for this purpose?I also want to use shared element transitions on the image.

[image: Next]

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewPager` will definitely need fragments. I guess you know that. The second activity whose snapshot you posted will NOT NEED any fragments. It is a simple combination of 3 layouts -> `FrameLayout`,`LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`. So, it is a simple **activity**

Comment: But is it still possible to do a shared element transition between the two?

Comment: @JudeFernandes, yeah obviously it is possible. Googling for furthur info will help you

Comment: The codes that i found online include transitions between 2 activities or 2 fragments but not between a fragment and activity and the code in each case is quite different,if you could provide me with a working code that would be very helpful.

Comment: @JudeFernandes, yeah you should have found correct info. It may be possible that transitions between an activity and a fragment may not be possible. But take my word, it is 100% possible between 2 activities. The fragments are contained within the activity itself. So, you must have transitions between the parent activity and the second activity. Its as simple as that